# Inserting relationships into a table which connects 3 tables with many to many relationships with SQLALchemy - python

Tags: python, insert, sqlalchemy, many-to-many, foreign-key-relationship

Below you can see how some tables of my database are related.

[image: diagram]

As you can see the table in the middle is connecting 3 tables with many-to-many relationships...

1. One gene can be expressed in more than one organ and studied in more than one experimen
2. In one organ, more than one gene can be expressed and one organ can be studied in more than one experiment.
3. In one experiment, more than one gene and organ can be studied

I am using SQLAlchemy to insert data. I know how to add a many-to-many relationships with a table that is connecting 2 tables, and more or less I do it like this:

```
def add_data():
    session=Session()
    gene = "BRCA2"
    gene_to_add = Gene(gene_name = gene)
    session.add(gene_to_add)

    experiment = "experiment1"
    experiment_to_add = Experiment(experimentAccession = experiment)
    gene_to_add.experiment_rel.append(experiment_to_add)

    organ = "brain"
    organ_to_add = Organ(organName = organ)

    session.commit()
    session.close()
```

But I don't know how to add a new relationship (organs table in this case). I tried with extend instead of append, but it doesn't works...

Does anyone know how to solve this kind of situation? Maybe the structure of the database should change... any help would be much appreciated

Comment: To clarify the model further: how/where would you like to store the results of the experiments? This might help refine the mapping of the existing model.

Answer (score 2):

You can always use an [Association Object](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_7/orm/relationships.html#association-object):

```
class Genes2Experiments2Organs(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'genes2experiments2organs'
    gene_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('genes.id'), primary_key=True)
    experiment_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('experiments.id'), primary_key=True)
    organ_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('organs.id'), primary_key=True)
    # relationships
    gene = relationship("Gene", backref="map") 
    experiment = relationship("Experiment", backref="map") 
    organ = relationship("Organ", backref="map") 


class Gene(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'genes'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    gene_name = Column(String)

class Experiment(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'experiments'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    experimentAccession = Column(String)

class Organ(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'organs'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    organName = Column(String)

###########################################
def add_data():
    session = Session()
    gene = "BRCA2"
    gene_to_add = Gene(gene_name = gene)
    #session.add(gene_to_add)

    experiment = "experiment1"
    experiment_to_add = Experiment(experimentAccession = experiment)
    #session.add(experiment_to_add)

    organ = "brain"
    organ_to_add = Organ(organName = organ)
    #session.add(organ_to_add)

    #gene_to_add.experiment_rel.append(experiment_to_add)
    assoc_obj_to_add = Genes2Experiments2Organs(
        gene = gene_to_add,
        experiment = experiment_to_add,
        organ = organ_to_add,
        )

    session.add(assoc_obj_to_add)

    session.commit()
    session.close()

add_data()
```