# Association table between 2 association tables. Is this the correct approach?

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, sqlalchemy

There are 3 initial tables, **Product**, **User**, and **Tag**. (Not really a product table but it makes for a simpler example)

There's a many-to-many relationship between a **User** and **Product**, as well as between a **User** and **Tag**. So, I created 2 association tables for this relationship -> **UserProduct** and **UserTag**

Now, a user can create multiple tags, and add those tags to a product. From my knowledge, this can be achieved by creating another association table, **UserProductTag**, between the association tables **UserProduct** and **UserTag**.

I wasn't able to find many examples of this use case on the internet. That made me wonder, is this the correct approach? Or am I overdoing normalization?

This gets further complicated by the fact that I've to achieve this in SQLAlchemy as well and I've no idea (but I guess that's a different question).

Comment: Your approach is quite reasonable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe what you are looking for is what is often called ["ternary relationship"](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/Ternary-Relationship-in-Database).

Please see these two SO questions and answers to give you implementation ideas:

- [How to three-way many-to-many relationship in flask-sqlalchemy](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23035662)
- [Inserting relationships into a table which connects 3 tables with many to many relationships with SQLALchemy - python](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16103009)