# Sqlalchemy multiple many to many

Tags: python, sql, postgresql, sqlalchemy, model

I'm pretty new to Sqlalchemy and in general I'm not a SQL guru. I'm currently trying to build a model to manage different workspaces (you can see them as organizations), with the following requirements:

- A user can create multiple workspaces
- When a user creates a workspace, it has automatically assigned the "owner" Role
- One user can have just one role in the workspace
- Every workspace can contain multiple users with different roles
- In every workspace I can create Teams
- Different workspaces can have the same team name (but different team_id)
- Teams can live without users assigned to them, but they stick to workspaces
- Users can be assigned to a team by the owner of the workspace

This is the code I wrote until now:

```py
class User(Base):
    __tablename__ = "user"
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    email = Column(String, unique=True, index=True, nullable=False)
    first_name = Column(String)
    last_name = Column(String)
    password = Column(String, nullable=False)
    is_active = Column(Boolean, default=False)
    created_at = Column(DateTime, default=datetime.utcnow)


class Workspace(Base):
    __tablename__ = "workspace"
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    name = Column(String)
    description = Column(String)
    created_at = Column(DateTime, default=datetime.utcnow)
    users = relationship(User, lambda: user_workspace, backref='workspaces')


class Role(Base):
    __tablename__ = "role"
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    name = Column(String)
    capabilities = Column(Integer)



class Team(Base):
    __tablename__ = "team"
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    name = Column(String)
    workspace = relationship(Workspace, lambda: user_workspace, backref='teams')


user_workspace = Table(
    'user_workspace', Base.metadata,
    Column('user_id', Integer, ForeignKey(User.id), primary_key=True),
    Column('workspace_id', Integer, ForeignKey(Workspace.id), primary_key=True),
)
```

Now if I create a new workspace I'm able to automatically populate the `user_workspace` table with the `workspace_id` and the `user_id`. But currently I'm a bit blocked on how to extend the `user_workspace` table so it can contain references also to `role_id` and `team_id`.

Anyone can suggest me the best approach? I searched a lot, but I didn't really find something similar to this (maybe it's just me being newbie with that stuff). Thanks you in advance!

Comment: Take a look at [Association Object](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/basic_relationships.html#association-object).

Maybe also [this question/answer](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/basic_relationships.html#association-object).

Comment: yeah I was exactly looking at it, but still far from understanding what I should do :)

Comment: @van btw your link to "this question/answer" always goes to Association Object doc

Comment: Apologies: [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16103009/)